# Shortest path between two nodes multiple times

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

In an undirected but weighted graph, I am trying to find the shortest path (distance) between two nodes multiple times. If I use Dijkstra, then I can find the distance between one node and every other node. Doing separate Dijkstras for each starting node is inefficient with O(E V logV). Is there a way for a more efficient method to do this?

What if there were some constraints, say there are n predefined nodes that I need to query the distance to any of them? Would that change the algorithm to solve this problem? I suspect there is a common algorithm for this, but I've never heard of this before. In my graph, the number of edges is approximately three times the number of nodes. (Three edges per node).

Comment: You might mean the "all pairs shortest path" problem. Floy-Warshall is one algorithm.

Comment: Yes, there is a more efficient way to find the shortest path between two nodes multiple times in an undirected weighted graph. One way to achieve this is by using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

The Floyd-Warshall algorithm is an all-pairs shortest path algorithm that works by maintaining a distance matrix, where the entry dist[i][j] represents the shortest distance between nodes i and j. The algorithm then updates the entries of the distance matrix iteratively by considering all possible intermediate nodes.

Comment: Part 1 )  

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int INF = 1e9;

int main() {
    int n, m;  // n: number of nodes, m: number of edges
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<vector<int>> dist(n, vector<int>(n, INF));  // initialize distance matrix with INF
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int u, v, w;
        cin >> u >> v >> w;
        dist[u][v] = dist[v][u] = w;  // update distance matrix
    }

Comment: Part 2) 
    // Floyd-Warshall algorithm
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                dist[i][j] = min(dist[i][j], dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Query distances between two nodes
    int q;
    cin >> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int u, v;
        cin >> u >> v;
        cout << "Distance between nodes " << u << " and " << v << " is " << dist[u][v] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Whilst Floyd-Warshall algorithm works, it runs in O(n^3) time. How would this be any more efficient than running Dijkstra V times, which will still be more efficient than Floyd-Warshall algorithm?

Comment: Note that most of the time when you see O notation you're getting the worst case. Every now and then, you'll see the term *amortized* used when you rarely see the worst case. And there are cases where a better O gets its ass kicked by a worse O because of practical matters that O notation leaves out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a more efficient way to find the shortest path (distance) between two nodes in an undirected weighted graph than running Dijkstra's algorithm for each starting node. One approach is to use the Bidirectional Dijkstra algorithm.

The Bidirectional Dijkstra algorithm works by running two instances of Dijkstra's algorithm at the same time, one starting from the source node and the other starting from the target node. The algorithm continues to run until the two searches meet at some node in the middle. At this point, the algorithm has found the shortest path between the two nodes.

The Bidirectional Dijkstra algorithm can be more efficient than running Dijkstra's algorithm separately for each starting node, as it explores the graph from both ends simultaneously and can stop early once the two searches meet in the middle. The time complexity of the Bidirectional Dijkstra algorithm is O(E + V log V), which is faster than the O(E V log V) time complexity of running Dijkstra's algorithm separately for each starting node.

If there are n predefined nodes that you need to query the distance to any of them, one approach is to run n instances of the Bidirectional Dijkstra algorithm, one for each predefined node as the starting node, and store the resulting distances in a data structure such as an array or a map. This way, you can look up the distances between any two nodes in constant time by querying the data structure. The time complexity of this approach is O(n(E + V log V)), which is faster than running Dijkstra's algorithm separately for each starting node, but slower than running a single instance of the Bidirectional Dijkstra algorithm.